# How to find correlation coefficients in a loop?

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
Account_tenure_years = c(982,983,984,985,986,987,988)
N=c(12328,18990,21255,27996,32014,15487,4347)
Y=c(76,64,61,76,94,55,11)
df_table_account_tenure_vs_PPC = data.frame(Account_tenure_years,N,Y)

The dataset looks like this:

Account_tenure_years   N     Y
982                  12328  76
983                  18990  64
984                  21255  61
985                  27996  76
986                  32014  94
987                  15487  55
988                   4347  11
```

What I want to do is this:

I want to find `correlation` between any two of the `Account_tenure_years`, example, `982,983` and find the `correlation coefficient` with `N` and `Y columns` i.e I want to find the `correlation coefficient` of the below table

```
  Account_tenure_years   N     Y
  982                  12328  76
  983                  18990  64
```

Now I want to repeat this 8C2 times i.e 28 times. Taking different rows and finding the `correlation coefficient` in each case.
i.e in the next iteration I would want :

```
 Account_tenure_years   N     Y
  983                  18990  64
  984                  21255  61
```

And find its `correlation coefficient`. Now after I have received all those 28 `correlation coefficients`, I `average` them out and find a `mean` `correlation coefficient` for the entire dataset.

How do I do this in R?

Ok lets get this straight if I find out the correlation coefficient between the columns

```
Account_tenure_years column, N
```

Also if I try to find out the correlation coefficient between the columns

```
Account_tenure_years column, Y
```

And if I find negative correlation coefficients in each case , can we infer anything from that?

Comment: You need the `correlation coefficient` count for each of the rows right? I am not understanding that how it can be 28 times?

Comment: @Saurabh Chauhan Lets make it simpler.Lets say you do the correlation coefficient between the Account_tenure_years and N and then between Account_tenure_years and Y and then find out the correlation in each case. If ,lets say, you get a negative correlation in both cases, statistically what do you infer?Or can anything be inferred?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to calculate `correlation coefficient` for each case because it is usually calculated for the entire dataset.

Comment: No no you see the main focus here is to find the correlation coefficient for the dataset but it is a 8 $\times$ 3 dataset, you have to find out the correlation between the first and the second column and then between the first and the third column.

Comment: Could you please check my answer? I have done the same thing for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an ideal way to calculate `correlation coefficient` for each case. It should be calculated for the entire dataset:

```
Account_tenure_years = c(982,983,984,985,986,987,988)
N=c(12328,18990,21255,27996,32014,15487,4347)
Y=c(76,64,61,76,94,55,11)
df = data.frame(Account_tenure_years,N,Y)

cor(df$Account_tenure_years,df$N)
cor(df$Account_tenure_years,df$Y)
```

Output is as shown below:

```
> cor(df$Account_tenure_years,df$N)
[1] -0.1662244
> cor(df$Account_tenure_years,df$Y)
[1] -0.5332263
```

You can inferred that data is negatively correlated. It means increase in the value of `Account_tenure_years` will decrease the value of `N` and `Y` or vice-versa.

Please feel free to correct me!

Answer (score 0):

It should be easier to do this to transpose your data,  And the best part is that you don't even need to write a loop.

try this:

```r
dt <- data.table::fread("
Account_tenure_years   N     Y
982                  12328  76
983                  18990  64
984                  21255  61
985                  27996  76
986                  32014  94
987                  15487  55
988                   4347  11
")


dt.t <- as.data.frame(t(dt[, 2:3]))

colnames(dt.t) = dt$Account_tenure_years
# transpose
dt.t
#>     982   983   984   985   986   987  988
#> N 12328 18990 21255 27996 32014 15487 4347
#> Y    76    64    61    76    94    55   11

# calculate correlation matrix, read more help(cor)
cor(dt.t)
#>     982 983 984 985 986 987 988
#> 982   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
#> 983   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
#> 984   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
#> 985   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
#> 986   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
#> 987   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
#> 988   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Created on 2018-07-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand how you want to compute correlation coefficients between two variables with only one observation for each. Therefore, I assume you have more rows than provided here.

First define all combinations:

```
combinations <- combn(df_table_account_tenure_vs_PPC$Account_tenure_years, 2)
```

For each combination, you want to extract the corresponding rows and compute the correlation coefficients for each variable:

```
coefficients <- apply(combinations, 2, function(x, df_table_account_tenure_vs_PPC){
    coef <- sapply(c("N", "Y"), function(v, x, df_table_account_tenure_vs_PPC){
        c <- cor(df_table_account_tenure_vs_PPC[df_table_account_tenure_vs_PPC == x[1], v], df_table_account_tenure_vs_PPC[df_table_account_tenure_vs_PPC == x[2], v])
        return(c)},
    x, df_table_account_tenure_vs_PPC)
    return(c(x, coef))},
df_table_account_tenure_vs_PPC)
```

Then, you can aggregate your results in a data.frame:

```
df <- as.data.frame(t(coefficients))
colnames(df) <- c("Year1", "Year2", "N_cor", "Y_cor")
```

This should work. Please tell me if you have any problem.
Again, make sure you have more than one observation in each condition if you want a meaningful correlation coefficient.

Comment: Can you please tell me what the argument 'combinations' stands for- it gives an error. Please give an edit to show it. Btw thanks for the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I did not format my answer correctly, you should see it better now.

Comment: df <- do.call(rbind, coefficients) shows an error Error in do.call(rbind, coefficients) : second argument must be a list

Comment: I've updated my answer again to address this (I never think through the apply output the first time). You should have a data.frame filled with NA because you have only one observation per year, with more observations per year, it should work.

Comment: I've just noticed your comments under your question. Please clarify the question because it seems that what you ask in the comment is not what you ask in the question. Therefore my answer may not solve the problem you want to solve as I may not have understood it well.

Do you want the correlation coefficient between years (I first understood that), or between variables?

Comment: it is sad to say that N_cor and Y-cor columns , there is NA .

Comment: If you try to calculate the correlation between a single observation then it should be `NA`.

Comment: Yeah, this is expected since it measures correlation between 2 values, and it does not make sense. As I have already said, it would work if you had more values per year. Please make sure you understand what a correlation coefficient is, and what correlation you want to measure.

Comment: @Hobo Sheep no please see if what Saurabh Chauhan answers is correct or not.

Comment: @C.Gupta I believe the answer of Saurabh Chauban is correct. At least it makes sense and seems to answer what you describe in the comments to your initial question.